# File url [tmp_name] after upload via Typo3 backend

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm building a typo3 extension and in a backend plugin I want to build a image upload form. I seem not to get the correct $_Files url. The following fluid form is used:

```
<f:form action="customerSliderImages" id="customerSliderImages">
    <f:form.upload name="custSlider[sliderimage]" />
    <f:form.submit value="Upload" />
</f:form>
```

I want to have the [name] and [tmp_name] to store the image, but I don't get the correct url. Also I don't know to echo $_Files for debugging. I tried the following but not working:

```
$_FILES["tx_mtclnt_user_mtclntmtcus"]["tmp_name"]["custSlider"]['sliderimage']
$_FILES["tx_mtclnt_user_mtclntmtcus"]["name"]["custSlider"]['sliderimage']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you did not define the `enctype` attribute on the `<f:form>` tag.

```
<f:form ... enctype="multipart/form-data"> ... </f:form>
```

See also:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp
- http://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#f:form